# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CommonModule

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I'm new in NEST.js world, and I trying to create simple middleware.
First, I created a middleware with this command:

```
nest g middleware common/middleware/logging
```

And after I add my code

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class LoggingMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    console.time('Request-response time');
    console.log('Hi from middleware!');

    res.on('finish', () => console.timeEnd('Request-response time'));
    next();
  }
}
```

And finally, I add the middleware

```
import { Module, MiddlewareConsumer } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ApiKeyGuard } from './guards/api-key.guard';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { LoggingMiddleware } from './middleware/logging.middleware';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: ApiKeyGuard
    }

  ]
})
export class CommonModule {
  constructor(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(LoggingMiddleware).forRoutes('*')
  }
}
```

But when i try to run it:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CommonModule (?). Please make
> sure that the argument Object at index [0] is available in the
> CommonModule context.
>
> Potential solutions:
>
> - If Object is a provider, is it part of the current CommonModule?
> - If Object is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within CommonModule?   @Module({
>   imports: [ /* the Module containing Object */ ]   })  +2ms Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CommonModule (?). Please make
>   sure that the argument Object at index [0] is available in the
>   CommonModule context.
>
> Potential solutions:
>
> - If Object is a provider, is it part of the current CommonModule?
> - If Object is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within CommonModule?   @Module({
>   imports: [ /* the Module containing Object */ ]   })

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MiddlewareConsumer` isn't a part of the `constructor`. Rather, your module class should implement `NestModule` and should have a `configure` method that takes in the `consumer: MiddlewareConsumer` as the first and only paramter.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: ApiKeyGuard
    }

  ]
})
export class CommonModule implmenets NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MidlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(LoggingMiddleware).forRoutes('*')
  }
}
```